# XSLT 1.0 adds extra spaces in between the strings

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT transformation where I extract Customer Name details. I am using XSLT 1.0. The transformation seems to have inserted extra spaces in between the strings. Examples and details below:

XML:

```
<Root>
   <Customer>
      <PrimaryGuest>
       <FirstName>Jonathan (Jonny)</FirstName>
       <LastName>Doe</LastName> 
       <MiddleName>Lewis</MiddleName>
     </PrimaryGuest>
     <PrimaryGuest>
       <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
       <LastName>Doe</LastName> 
       <MiddleName>L</MiddleName>
     </PrimaryGuest>
  </Customer>
</Root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl xsl xsd exslt"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="TravelerName">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$LOB = 11">
        <xsl:for-each select="Root/Customer/PrimaryGuest | Root/PriorCustomer/PrimaryGuest">
         <xsl:if test="(position() = '1')">[</xsl:if>
            <xsl:variable name="FirstName">
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="LastName">
                <xsl:value-of select="LastName" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="MiddleName">
                <xsl:value-of select="MiddleName" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="SuffixName">
                <xsl:value-of select="SuffixName" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="TravelerName">
                <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('[&quot;',$FirstName, '&quot;, ', '&quot;', $LastName, '&quot;, ', '&quot;', $MiddleName, '&quot;, ', '&quot;', $SuffixName, '&quot;]')" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$TravelerName" />
                <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">, </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="(position() = last())">]</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

OUTPUT:

```
TravelerName:[[["Jonathan       (Jonny)", "Doe", "Lewis", ""], ["Mary", "Doe", "L", ""] ]]
```

I have tried a few different ways. It makes sense to me, if I see leading or trailing spaces but not spaces in between. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: It is not reproducible in my local eclipse where I tried with 'JRE instance default' and 'Xalan 2.7.1'. I am not sure what is in my deployment environment. I don't have any processors added to my war.

Comment: To find out what processor you are using, add `<xsl:comment select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` to your stylesheet.

Comment: I tried <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></xsl:comment>. It doesn't print anything when I run a Unit Test against the stylesheet in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

### The shortest possible answer

Maybe your **source XML** contains e.g. a *Tab* character or extra spaces
(e.g. in *FirstName*)?
To make the script resistant to such cases, use `normalize-space` function.

### And now a longer version

I checked your original source XML with slightly modified version
of your XSLT script, using version **1.0** and **Xalan** processor,
see http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79r and the output is OK.

Notice that I changed `select` in `for-each` to `Root/*/PrimaryGuest`.

The reason is that in **XSLT 1.0** `|` (union operator) in `select` does not
work (although it works in `match` expression).
To verify this on "my" example, add `| x` to the `select` attribute
(in `for-each`) and the output will be shorter.

If you want to restrict the `select` range to *Customer* and *PriorCustomer*,
add after the `*` a predicate: `[name()='Customer' or name()='PriorCustomer']`.

**Another remark:**

In your code I see a weird practice:
You create a variable (e.g. `FirstName`), containing an element with just the same name,
and the **only** purpose of this variable is to output its value in `value-of` (in this case `$FirstName`).

I think it is much simpler to use just the **element name**, without creating
any temporary variables, as I did in my script.

Note also that initial `[` and trailing `]` can be output
before and after the `for-each` loop, respectively.
This change makes the script more effective and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. This is very useful!
I am going to give this a try. I will update if it works, in a couple of days/weeks.